# VTK: rotate a 3D model and capture its depth map

Tags: c++, vtk

Currently, based on the VTK ZBuffer example, I iteratively rotate the 3D model and capture each time the depth map. The issue is that although the model rotates the output images contain all the first depth map.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

...variable declaration/initialization

//read off file
offReader->SetFileName(argv[1]);
offReader->Update(); 

int step = 30; std::string out;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
    mapper->NewInstance();
    actor->NewInstance();
    renWin->NewInstance();
    renderer->NewInstance();

    mapper->SetInputData(polyData);
    actor->SetMapper(mapper);

    out = std::to_string(i);

    actor->RotateZ(step*i);

    renWin->AddRenderer(renderer);

    renderer->AddActor(actor);
    renderer->SetBackground(1, 1, 1);
    renWin->Render(); 

    // Create Depth Map
    filter->NewInstance();
    scale->NewInstance();
    imageWriter->NewInstance();

    filter->SetInput(renWin);
    filter->SetMagnification(3);
    filter->SetInputBufferTypeToZBuffer();        //Extract z buffer value
    filter->Update();

    scale->SetOutputScalarTypeToUnsignedChar();     
    scale->SetInputConnection(filter->GetOutputPort());     
    scale->SetShift(0);
    scale->SetScale(-255);
    scale->Update();

    std::string out1 = out + "_depth.bmp";
    std::cout << " " << out1 << std::endl;

    // Write surface map as a .bmp image
    imageWriter->SetFileName(out1.c_str());
    imageWriter->SetInputConnection(scale->GetOutputPort());
    imageWriter->Update();
    imageWriter->Write();

    filter->RemoveAllInputs();
    scale->RemoveAllInputs();
    imageWriter->RemoveAllInputs();
    renderer->RemoveActor(actor);
    renWin->RemoveRenderer(renderer); 

    .... remaining script

}
```

The output depth maps are all **identical**. [0_depth.bmp, 1_depth.bmp & 2_depth.bmp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKPGo.jpg)

Has anyone encountered the same issue? If yes, what could be a potential solution.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by introducing a function within the rotation took place. Apparently it was a matter of a variable content update issue, that could be solved in a more straight forward way.

Comment: so did the actor need to be updated post the rotation call?

Comment: I tried updating/refreshing actor, mapper, renWin, scale, filter and imageWriter. It did not work. 

Apparently there is a more straightforward way.

I placed all rotation inside a function and also rendered the renWin within the function. The function call:
WriteDepthMap(i,actor,renderer, renWin);